# Find the smallest N to complete the task: "Write a true self-reflective statement about the digits from 0 to N"

Tags: mathematics

Following [this question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/1901/28), consider the case where we change the number of digits and formulate the task like this:

> Write the statement like "This statement contains $M_0$ 0's, $M_1$ 1, ..., $M_N$ N's", which is true. You must write about all digits, which statement includes: that all $M_i (i = 0, .., N)$ must be written with $0, .., N$ digits only.

**What is the smallest $N$ possible here?**

---

Similarly to the given answer for $N=9$:

> **1** 0's, **7** 1's, **3** 2's, **2** 3's, **1** 4's, **1** 5's, **1** 6's, **2** 7's, **1** 8's, and **1** 9's.

I can construct answer for $N=6$:

> **1** 0's, **4** 1's, **3** 2's, **2** 3's, **2** 4's, **1** 5's, **1** 6's.

but the same approach fails for $N=5$. Meanwhile this doesn't prove that $N \le 5$ is not possible to achieve.

Comment: Your approach for $N = 5$ fails because it's known that there's no solution to $N = 5$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've seen this problem for numbers from $1$ to $N$ before, but not for $0$ to $N$.

If the statements are from $1$ to $N$, the minimum you can have is $4$, as follows:

> This statement contains **2** 1's, **3** 2's, **2** 3's, and **1** 4.

---

Now note that in the case from $0$ to $N$, you're guaranteed that there is only ever one $0$, because there is never $0$ of any other number. So, a trivial solution exists for $N = 0$:

> This statement contains **1** 0.

And for $N = 1$:

> This statement contains **1** 0 and **2** 1's.

And for $N = 2$:

> This statement contains **1** 0, **3** 1's, and **1** 2.

However, what these statements all have in common is that they involve writing a number greater than the maximum number being counted, which means that the sentence only describes *some* of the numbers, not all of them. The smallest statement that fits your new criterion is indeed $N = 3$:

> This statement contains **1** 0, **2** 1's, **3** 2's, **2** 3's, **and no other numbers**.

Comment: So you are saying that $N=5$ doesn't have an solution and $N=4$ doesn't, and $N\le2$ doesn't? Could you prove it?

Comment: Actually, you're right. A smaller, trivial solution exists.

Comment: Oh. Good catch. I missed this moment. I corrected the question to exclude trivial solutions. I am interested in something different (what you showed before for $N=3$). Sorry.

Comment: That's why this problem is generally formulated from $1$ to $N$ - so you don't have the awkwardness with $0$ allowing overflows.

Comment: But if you have 2 1s, you also have 1 2, so you need to bump N up. I don't think this works as a solution - otherwise I'd just say I have A 1s in hexadecimal in the original problem.

Comment: @Emrakul: The statement contains 1 0 and 2 1's, but it says nothing about the number of 2's.

Comment: @JoeZ. Are you sure you can only have 1 zero in the $0$ to $N$ case? What about something like `This statement has 2 0's, 10 1's, 11111111 2's, ...`.

Comment: In cases involving up to one digit, there can never be more than one digit's worth of any number.

Comment: It depends whether you count $10$ as a $10$ or as one $1$ and one $0$.  If as one $1$ and one $0$ you can have two (or more) $0$s.

Comment: No; it's literally impossible simply because there aren't enough digits to go around. Suppose that there's $10$ of some number and two $0$'s. Then there's at least two $2$'s as well (and thereby at least two $3$'s, since there are two 0's and two 2's), but only $21$ digits in total. You just can't fit them all.

Comment: @JoeZ.: I don't get you, are you claiming that there can't be $10$ or that there can't be *two-digit* number? Because there is a solution with two-digit number: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/172763/92861

Comment: Hmm, seems I was wrong, then.