# Autobiographical numbers

Tags: mathematics

An autobiographical number is a number that describes its own digits. The first digit (from left) specifies the number of 0s in the number, the next digit specifies the number of 1s in the number and so on. For example 2020 is an autobiographical number, because it contains two 0s, zero 1s, two 2s and zero 3s. What is the next autobiographical number after 2020?

Comment: Ooohh, excitement! This is related to what I called "self-describing numbers". I did a bunch of programming and I guess also "research" on those and finally found a proof that they all follow a certain pattern. Here are my posts on that: https://projectatmos.space/profile/1p8WCZnqqG6N3ZOsJxBgUTo/p1cNCw1OTsioTQBRk

Comment: Special cases of it are actually here already! https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/23503/40546 and https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/1904/40546 and https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/1901/40546

Comment: @FabianRöling thanks for the links!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I think the answer is

> **21200**

Step-by-step analysis:

> There are no other autobiographical numbers in the form of `2xxx`: Since we already have a 2, the two zeros must go to 1s and 3s. This just leads to the number 2020 which does not meet the condition (after 2020).

> There are no other four-digit autobiographical numbers higher than that: `3xxx` is impossible because we have a three, so the last digit is nonzero, and then there's not enough space to put three zeros. `4xxx` or higher is obviously impossible.

> There are no five-digit autobiographical numbers in the form of `1xxxx`: There are only one zero, so we have at least three distinct digits out of `1234`. But the minimum sum of the three digits is 1+2+3=6, so it does not fit into five digits.

> 21200 is the only autobiographical number in the form of `2xxxx`: There must be two zeros, and the 2 position is nonzero. Due to the same digit sum argument, threes and fours must be zero, giving `2xx00`. The only possible nonzero 2-digit combination that sums to 3 is `12`, so there are two 2s and one 1. The autobiographical number that matches this is **21200**, which has two zeros, one 1, two 2s, no 3s and no 4s.

Trivia:

> After I posted the solution, I googled the term and I found that "autobiographical numbers" is a real name for such numbers. And there exists an OEIS sequence [A046043](http://oeis.org/A046043) that lists up all autobiographical numbers: 1210, 2020, **21200**, 3211000, 42101000, 521001000, 6210001000.

Comment: +1! Just beat me to it :-)

Comment: Hi, and welcome to PSE! Please start your puzzling adventure by clicking [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tour).

Comment: You got it. Well done!